# Как в git объединить старые коммиты в один?

Tags: git

У меня есть git репозиторий, в котором я хочу объединить некоторые старые коммиты в один.

Эти коммиты не последние, я знаю, что это изменит git историю.

Вот пример того, что я хочу сделать, есть эти коммиты:

[image: коммиты]

Я хочу их всех объединить в один общий коммит "Сделал лог os соединения", который будет содержать их суммарные изменения, т. е. по сути squash, только для старых коммитов.

Это был пример, на его основе я хочу сделать множество объединений.

Так как это сделать?

Comment: Раз в курсе переписывания истории, то интерактивный rebase поможет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нормального способа нет это сделать, если коммиты очень глубоко в истории. Rebase заставит вас заново решать все конфликты merge коммитов.

По этому я написал свою утилиту, которая позволяет это делать автоматически: https://github.com/lokha/git-recreator

Answer (score 1):

Имеем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выполняем:

```bsh
git rebase -i 5537cb77d8dcb72dd70a852efdec2108c99ad3fe
```

Где `5537cb77d8dcb72dd70a852efdec2108c99ad3fe` - SHA коммита **выше** которого хотим что-то схлопнуть (в Вашем случае это SHA коммита с сообщением `Merge remote...`).

Меняем `pick` на `squash` у тех коммитов, которые хотим свернуть в самый верхний `pick` коммит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По необходимости меняем сообщения новых коммитов.

После этого имеем:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. "склеили" `commit2` и `commit3`, `commit4` и `commit5`.

Запушить эти изменения на `remote` получится только с флагом `-f`**orce**.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать rebase всей истории от первого объединяемого коммита до последнего имеющегося включительно на тот же коммит, который является предком первого объединяемого.

В процессе rebase'а часть коммитов можно объединить, например, в интерактивном режиме.

Некоторые gui-обертки для git (например TortoiseGit) позволяют автоматизировать этот процесс, но всё равно это будет выполнено посредствам git rebase